# Page redirect PHP/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

maybe you can help me. I'm working with jQuery mobile and PHP.

I have done a schedule where someone can put in a day and a temperature to this day. You can modifiy the temperature and here is my Problem. I do the modify with php. After the value is changed I would like to Redirect to the following page http://localaddress/temperatureconrol/#t1.

I do this with the Header function of PHP but it doesn't work. It doesn't Redirect, but in the browser line stands http://192.168.0.61/temperaturecontrol/modifyTemperatureProfile.php. It is the file you can see the code from below.  Can someone help me? Should I solve this in another way?

I'm a newbe. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
<?php
    include("logic/dbManager.php");


    $dbManager = new dbManager();
    $timetableentryid = $_POST['timetableentry-id'];
    $desiredtemp = $_POST['desired_temperature'];
    $day = $_POST['input-day'];
    $timetableid = $_POST['input-timetableid'];


    if (isset($_POST["modify-temperatureprofile-button"]))
    {

        $dbManager->updateDB("Update TimetableEntriesAgrar set desiredtemp = $desiredtemp where id = $timetableentryid;");
        $dbManager->closeDB();

    }        

    header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently"); 
    header("Location: http://192.168.0.61/temperaturecontrol/#t1");


    exit; 

?>
```

Comment: Can't help without viewing your code.

Comment: when you say it doesn't work, what does happen? if you google "stack overflow php 301" or look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php you will find lots of good information

Comment: The Problem is it gives no error. I Redirects to 192.168.0.61/temperatureprofilecontrol/modifyTemperatureProfile.php. That is file in which I'm standing and want to Redirect.

Comment: your redirect code working fine , check your top code

Comment: <?php
    header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: http://192.168.0.61/temperaturecontrol/#t1");
    exit;
?>

it is working fine

Comment: try something like this: echo "<script>location.href='http://192.168.0.61/temperaturecontrol/#t1'</script>";

Comment: I did also try JavaScript. But the same result as with php (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is solved. window.location.replace(http://192.168.0.61/temperaturecontrol#1) solved it.